# Js Convert number into buffer array[4]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to print a number value into an array of 4 value [ uint32_t]

Exemple `255` => `[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF]`

a want to send this value from Nodejs server to Arduino

is there any native sollution or proposition ?

Comment: So you want to convert a value into 4 separate bytes? What have you tried?

Comment: I used this function `intToBytes = (value)=> {
let array = []
array[3] = value % 256
array[2] = (value >> 8) % 256
array[1] = (value >> 16) % 256
array[0] = (value >> 24) % 256
return array
}`
i wanna know if there is an easier way to do it with nodejs or native function

Comment: Thanks @MikeC ^^

Comment: @MikeC The native solution would be using typed arrays and DataView. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724367/js-convert-number-into-buffer-array4/42724615#42724615).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do it - e.g. you can shift the numbers and zero out all the bits but the 8 least significant ones.

For example:

```js
const conv = num => [
  (num >> 24) & 255,
  (num >> 16) & 255,
  (num >> 8) & 255,
  num & 255,
];

console.log(conv(16));
console.log(conv(255));
console.log(conv(256));
console.log(conv(640));
console.log(conv(32768));
```

Or, you can take a completely different approach and instead of telling the computer how to exactly shift the bits, you can tell it to get a 4 byte buffer, store a 32-bit number and show it to you as an array of four 8-bit numbers, using the new typed arrays in JavaScript:

```js
const conv = num => {
  let b = new ArrayBuffer(4);
  new DataView(b).setUint32(0, num);
  return Array.from(new Uint8Array(b));
}

console.log(conv(16));
console.log(conv(255));
console.log(conv(256));
console.log(conv(640));
console.log(conv(32768));
```

The result is the same but this time you don't need to know which way to shift bits and how to mask them. This is using some new features of JavaScript. For more info see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView

Note that this is all using big-endian format like the example in your question. But keep in mind that numbers can be represented with little-endian formats as well. See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Thank you @rsp i think that this is the optimal sollution ^^

Comment: @MohamedElAmineDADDOU I'm glad it helped. You can see the updated answer for a second way to do it. If the answer helped you then you can consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that other people who search for the question can see that it has been answered.

Comment: your answer helped me alot, Thanks for citing the resources so i can understand the second solution